# Errorlevel for ABAP syntax checker errors?

Tags: abap

There exists a Table in SAP for the syntax errors of the ABAP compiler `(table TRMSG)`, but the table does not store the errorlevels. (I.E whether an error should be displayed as Error, Warning or Information ).

I tried to look what the SCI does to generate the syntax errors, but it uses a keyword based function to generate them and therefore it is not traceable where the errorlevel comes from. (Waring, Error and Information)

For completion the keyword based function to check the syntax:

```
syntax-check for temp_itab_loc
             directory entry dic
             message         message
             line            line
             word            word
             include         include
             message-id      message_id
             id              'ERR'   table errors
             id              'MSG'   table warnings
             id              'INFO'  table infos
             id              'LTXT'  table longtext
             id               l_part table l_dummy.
```

Is there an other table where I can link an error with a level?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to "errorlevel" - could you please try to explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm refering to the type of "Error". Warning, Error and Information

Comment: Are you trying to figure out where SAP determines if a syntax issue is a warning or a hard error?  For example, "if" with no "endif" will throw a hard error, while using untranslatable text literals will generate a warning?

Comment: I need a reference to a Syntax Error before it occurs with Errorlevel.
TRMSG got all the messages but no level, thats my main issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would run [GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapgenerate_subroutine_pool.htm) , and from there know whether there is an error, if there is no error, then I would run syntax check.